# "Large" file uploads randomly failing when using HTTPS

Tags: asp.net, iis, file-upload, iis-7, backbone.js

We have a website which needs to allow users to upload files of sizes varying from a few KB to maybe 40MB at most. It's got a single-page front-end powered by Backbone.js (using [the jQuery form plugin](https://github.com/malsup/form) to upload files), and an API built with ASP.NET MVC, and it's hosted on IIS7. It is also served only over HTTPS.

In Chrome, files over about 4MB tend to fail to upload- often with no response from the server (when examining network responses). In Firefox, the same files often upload just fine, *but* occasionally give a 413 error (I uploaded the same file about five times in a row, on the last time I got a 413 error).

When we disable HTTPS, everything seems to work fine... but we need HTTPS on.

The web.config file includes `maxAllowedContentLength` and `maxRequestLength` values set to high-enough values.

Are there any more things we need to tweak or enable to get this to work more reliably over HTTPS?

Comment: Try to disable session if this is possible, and find some other way to  to be sure that the user is the right one to upload the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the executionTimeout for the httpRuntime config as well

Comment: Yeah, that's set to 1800 (30m).